# Determine $H(\mathbb{R, Q})$ and $H(\mathbb{R, Z})$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

I need to determine the relative (singular) homology groups of $\mathbb{R} \text{ mod } \mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R} \text{ mod } \mathbb{Z}$.

Any hints on what I need to know for this question?

Here is what I know so far:

By definition, the *singular homology groups* of a pair of spaces $(X,A)$ are the homology groups of the relative singular complex $S(X,A) = SX / SA$.

A *singular complex* is a sequence

$$ \cdots \leftarrow S_{q-1}X \leftarrow S_{q}X \leftarrow S_{q+1}X \leftarrow \cdots $$

with 
$$d_{q} \colon S_{q}X \rightarrow S_{q-1}X, \quad \sigma \mapsto \Sigma_{j=0}^{q} (-1)^{j}(\sigma_{q}\varepsilon_{q}^{j})$$

We recall that $S_{q}X$ is the free abelian group generated by the set of all singular q-simplices, that is, continuous maps $\sigma = \sigma_{q} \colon \Delta_{q} \rightarrow X$

I don't understand how to translate this into the concrete examples given.

Comment: Singular homology I presume?

What have you tried? Do you have a guess?

Comment: Yes, the singular homology. I have updated the question; the problem is I don't know how to approach the question.

Comment: You should use the long exact sequence of a pair of spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be either $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$. Hence $H_i(X) = 0$ for all $i > 0$, and thus by the long exact sequence in homology (recalling that $H_i(\mathbb{R}) = 0$ for $i > 0$ too) the following sequence is exact:
$$0 \to H_1(\mathbb{R},X) \to H_0(X) \to H_0(\mathbb{R}) \to H_0(\mathbb{R},X) \to 0$$
Now, $H_0(\mathbb{R}) = \mathbb{Z}$, and $H_0(X) = \bigoplus_{n = 0}^\infty \mathbb{Z}$ is a direct sum of a countable number of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ in both cases (both $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ are totally disconnected and countable). The map $f : \bigoplus_{n = 0}^\infty \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ sends $(z_n)$ to $\sum z_n$ (which is well-defined because only a finite number of $z_n$ are nonzero).

It follows that $H_0(\mathbb{R},X) = \operatorname{coker}(f) = 0$ ($f$ is surjective), and $H_1(\mathbb{R},X) = \ker(f)$ is also isomorphic to the direct sum of a countable number of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$.